# Android layout objects placement

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, button, android-linearlayout

I have this simple activity in my android app but I don't know how to place my button so it appears at the same position on various screen sizes.

I want the button to always be placed at the bottom of the screen. The screenshot shown is from a phone screen. When displayed on a larger screen the button is higher up.

How can I fix this?

Thanks

[See this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SSt2z.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I ended up doing. Thanks to everyone who posted, it helped me get in the right direction!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main"
    tools:context="xxxx.MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Dernières nouvelles Twitter"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="17dp"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:paddingTop="6dp"
        android:paddingRight="6dp"
        android:paddingBottom="6dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/listView_tweets"
        android:layout_above="@+id/buttonDisplay"
        android:choiceMode="none"
        android:paddingTop="25dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Horaire"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:id="@+id/buttonDisplay"
        android:onClick="buttonGotoDisplay"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use RelativeLayout with this parameter (android:layout_alignParentBottom="true")

```
<RelativeLayout 
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Button 
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
          android:text="Click Me!"/>  

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a `RelativeLayout`

If you have a `RelativeLayout` that fills the whole screen you should be able to use `android:layout_alignParentBottom` to move the button to the bottom of the screen.

If your button at the bottom doesn't show then probably the layout above it takes all the space. In this case you can put the button first in your layout file and position the rest of the layout above the views with `android:layout_above`.

Answer (score 0):

Make footerButton.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/footer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"       
    android:gravity="center" >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:text="HORAIRE"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And add it in all your layout file like below line:

**Android Activity_Layout**

```
  <RelativeLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:id="@+id/container"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent" >



  <!-- Footer aligned to bottom -->
  <include layout="@layout/footer" />

  <!-- Content above footer -->
  <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_above="@id/footer"
    android:layout_below="@id/header"
    android:gravity="center">

    <TextView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="Content goes here"
      android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
      android:textSize="20sp" />
  </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Hope it will solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

Have a look a [RelativeLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html). Use this ViewGroup and add a `Button` inside it with `alignParentBottom`

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="HORAIRE"
        android:layout_margins="<your_margin_in_dp>" />

</RelativeLayout>
```